# Can we have a bijective function that map an open interval to two open interval exist and what are the examples?

Tags: calculus

I’m trying to find a bijective continuous function that send $(0,1)$ for example to $(-\infty, 0) \cup (0, \infty)$. My current intuition is using log function for domain $(0.5,1)$ mapping to negative real number. For $(0,0.5]$, I can write it as the union of $[\frac{1}{(n+1)}, \frac{1}{n}]$ where the union of them becomes $(0,0.5]$. Then, using $x^{-1}$ function maps then to positive real number.

The function is continuous that log is continuous and $x^{-1}$ is continuous. It’s also bijective since each function is *bijective restricted* to domain. Is this example valid? I’m wondering if there’s a easier example.

Comment: Intermediate value theorem should help

Comment: The image of a connected set under a continuous mapping is connected.  So, no.

Comment: While spending time looking for that function, make sure you also block off some time for proving that it does not exist.

Comment: Well if you switch from euclidean topology to discrete topology in domain you could find plenty of examples. If you're working with euclidean topology you should stop searching...